# how to use default keystore while exporting an project in android

Tags: android

My project is already live in the play store and while updating the new app I got the error sha1 and MD5 in not matching. When I check the default SHA1 and MD5 key its different can any one tell me what can I do know so that I can upload my app to play store.
This is the error I get while uploading the new App update.

```
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. 
You must use the same certificate. 
Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
```

Answer (score 0):

With an app on Google Play, you MUST use ONE (and ONLY ONE) keystore for all versions. If you lost your keystore, you have to upload the app again as a new app.